# Making image align center of screen in html

Tags: html, css

I am loading image on iOS device. I want my image to be centered horizontally as well vertically center with all screens and orientation . I have tried it using table and td , It is aligning horizontally center but not aligning vertically middle . This is what I have tried 
html:

```
<table width=100% height=100%> 
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
            <img src="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: maybe [this link](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre3.html) can help you

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Instead of Table, You can achieve the same with `div` and `img`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VL2UF/)**

HTML

```
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
```

CSS

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

div {
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

div img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Good. Do not use tables if you can avoid them. But I would also recommend to use classes for this instead of making all divs and images in divs behave the same way.

Comment: It works, but the `position: absolute;` ruins my layout.

Comment: it also worth adding `max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;` for div img, otherwise scroll can appear if the image is bigger than the window

Answer (score 32):

There is a simple and easy way:

```
.centered {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Much easier than the answer of @Surjith.

Answer (score 2):

Try background image with `background-position:50% 50%`

http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/Ve6yz/3/

```
html, body
{
height: 100%;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Square_200x200.png);
background-position:50% 50%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this | **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2hMys/)**

```
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td class="height" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
            <img src="http://" width=100 height=100 />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
table{
    height:100%;
}
td.height{
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[**this seems to work**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ve6yz/)

**css**

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table width=100% height=100% border="1"> 
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Square_200x200.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you are wondering what i have changed, then let me tell you *even i am wondering the same* :)

but i think, making body and html tag more general helps...

Comment: this make it horizontally center , I want that to be vertically center of whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this simple code for a long time and it perfectly centers the image in the middle of the page.

```css
    body {padding:0; margin:0} .img {width:99%;}

    /* center and middle of the page */

    #jrXpress {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        display: block;
        z-index: 666;
    }
```

```html
<div id="jrXpress">
  <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <a href="https://www.jrxpress.com" title="jrXpress.com" alt="jrXpress.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://jrxpress.com/logo.jpg" width="280" height="80" border="0" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```