# Center a number of images vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hard time solving the following problem:

I'm trying to position a few pictures in the following manner:

- They all take the whole width of the screen (I know their number)
- The sequence of pictures is aligned in the middle vertically

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878342/making-image-align-center-of-screen-in-html), but it's not too helpful, as it allows centering only one image.
Also, `vertical-align` won't help much, since it only positions `inline` elements.

Here's my working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/3psbtqxv/1/

```css
body {
  padding-top: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  max-width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
<img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.Mf1e819b968b1241bf2a167c08096f7b8o0%26pid%3D15.1&f=1"><img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.Mf1e819b968b1241bf2a167c08096f7b8o0%26pid%3D15.1&f=1"><img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.Mf1e819b968b1241bf2a167c08096f7b8o0%26pid%3D15.1&f=1"><img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.Mf1e819b968b1241bf2a167c08096f7b8o0%26pid%3D15.1&f=1"><img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.Mf1e819b968b1241bf2a167c08096f7b8o0%26pid%3D15.1&f=1">
</body>
```

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Please be more clear with your question.

Comment: You should include a sample image of what you want to end result to be.  Also, what should happen on a mobile device, when the five images can't fit in a single screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First google search of "css position center of page" gave me this result:

[Quick CSS Trick: How To Center an Object Exactly In The Center](https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/)

In order to get the image exactly centered, it's a simple matter of applying a negative top margin of half the images height, and a negative left margin of half the images width. For this example, like so:

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

This works wonderfully when you know the size of the thing you are centering. If you don't know, or are thinking it might change and want to be future proof, try this:

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This works with your example.

Edit:
If you want it to take the whole screen width then use

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-0%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Somehow, the bulbs don't take up the whole screen width. Why is that?

Comment: @Jytug edited the answer to show how to make it take up the whole screen width. As per "why is that?", I guess because we shrink the size 50% from all sides to make the whole thing exactly in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
img {
  max-width:20%;
  height:auto;
  margin-top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to center child element is using flexbox.

```css
#parent{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  }
  #child{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  child
  </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve that, but most of the methods will need some update in your markup. I created this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e53pk9k8/6/) which center the images adding some extra wrappers around. I hope it helps.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="inner">
        <img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.Mf1e819b968b1241bf2a167c08096f7b8o0%26pid%3D15.1&f=1">
        <img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.Mf1e819b968b1241bf2a167c08096f7b8o0%26pid%3D15.1&f=1">
        <img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.Mf1e819b968b1241bf2a167c08096f7b8o0%26pid%3D15.1&f=1">
        <img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.Mf1e819b968b1241bf2a167c08096f7b8o0%26pid%3D15.1&f=1">
        <img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.Mf1e819b968b1241bf2a167c08096f7b8o0%26pid%3D15.1&f=1">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

.inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner img {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```