# How can I center a image in a HTML created by HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I have a very simple HTML document created with the HtmlAgilityPack, with a embedded image; (base64 format)

```
Public Report As New HtmlDocument()

Dim html As String = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img src=""data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANUAAADICAIAAADwajORAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARn"" alt=""Red dot"" align=""middle""/>
</body>
</html> "

    Report.LoadHtml(html)
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = Report.Text
```

The image displays on the left, I'd like to horizontally center it, how can this be done?

(The actual base64 image is shortened for obvious reasons)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making image align center of screen in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878342/making-image-align-center-of-screen-in-html)

Comment: I wish it was a duplicate Mortb, how can I embed this in my c#/vb.net code using HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: You have all the "page html" in your `html` string. You can put the css needed in a `<head><style>` tag that you insert at the top in the `<body>` tag. Like so :(example, use real code from the other answer)`<body><head><style>html, body
{
...
}</style></head>....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for was:

With the HtmlAgilityPack you can embed the CCS insite the HTLM like so:

```
       Dim html As String = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head><style>html, body {
height: 100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.center {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

}
</style></head>
<div>
    <img src=""data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANUAAADICAIAAADwajORA"" alt=""Red dot"" class=""center""/>
</div>
</body>
</html> "
```

Thanks to Mortb for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm not sure that you really need HtmlAgilityPack? It seems that the html is made up in your string which is passed to `HtmlDocument.LoadHtml(html)` and then you extract the (same?) string by using `HtmlDoucment.Text` property? I suspect that it might be possible to pass the original string directly to the `WebBrowser1` control directly like: `WebBrowser1.DocumentText = html`

Answer (score 0):

give the image style of

```
img{

        display:block;

        margin:auto;
}
```

or you can put the image inside a div tag and give the div this style:

```
div{

       width:; ==> give it any width you want

       height:; ==> give it any height want

       margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML images behave like text, so to center an image horizontally all you really need to do is add a `div` around it which centers all text:

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANUAAADICAIAAADwajORAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARn" alt="Red dot"/>
</div>
```

No special CSS workarounds needed.