# Moving an image to center of div when vertical align is not working

Tags: html, css, image

Hi I am struggling to center an image in a div vertically, wondering if anyone could assist.

```
<div id="homepage">
    <img src="assets/img/home-logo.png" id="home-logo">
</div>

#home-logo{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;}

#homepage{height: 100vh;
  background-color:#fff}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878342/making-image-align-center-of-screen-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using flexbox:

```
#homepage {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris" class="center"> 
.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. May It'll be helpful for you.

```
#home-logo{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; 
}

#homepage{height: 100vh;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use flex for the container and set `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center`

```css
#home-logo {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#homepage {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="homepage">
  <img src="assets/img/home-logo.png" id="home-logo">
</div>
```