# How do i place the image in the middle of the screen

Tags: javascript

i have made a bookmarklet to place an image but it only works on some website for example it works here [image source](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYUYElkT_30mOiDAiRs17z3UinaVcdsFyjQA&usqp=CAU) but not [google](https://google.com) it also won't place it in the middle it will just put it in the corner here is the bookmarklet

```
javascript:var myImage = new Image(100, 200);myImage.src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYUYElkT_30mOiDAiRs17z3UinaVcdsFyjQA&usqp=CAU';document.body.appendChild(myImage);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20878473/4129620

Comment: it needs to be in javascript though